# Using Linq2Twitter and cached OAuth tokens withing a ServiceStack api

Tags: c#, twitter, servicestack, linq-to-twitter

I want to use Linq2Twitter to make a Twitter API call from within a REST API written in ServiceStack.

I have the following information:

- ConsumerKey
- ConsumerSecret
- cached OAuth Token from when the user authenticated our app on the site
- cached OAuth TokenSecret from when the user authenticated our app on the site

How do I create the TwitterContext using this information so that I can make API calls? I am looking at the documentation and I see WebForm, MVC, Desktop examples, but none for my current use case. I don't think I can use the WebForm/MVC ones as those will try to redirect the user to an authorization page if the token/token secret are bad. I looked at the desktop example and it uses a pin authorization, which I don't think I can use either.

I understand that the token/token secret may be bad if the user decides to revoke access after I have cached these values, so I would need a way to verify and then do nothing if it fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question isn't exactly the same, but the authorizer concept might be interesting to you:

[How to use Linq to Twitter inside a web service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128036/how-to-use-linq-to-twitter-inside-a-web-service/18130215#18130215)

Essentially, you want to instantiate an authorizer, assigning values to the Credentials property, like this:

```
    var auth = new SingleUserAuthorizer
    {
        Credentials = new SingleUserInMemoryCredentials
        {
            ConsumerKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["twitterConsumerKey"],
            ConsumerSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["twitterConsumerSecret"],
            TwitterAccessToken = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["twitterAccessToken"],
            TwitterAccessTokenSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["twitterAccessTokenSecret"]
        }
    };
```

Then, instantiate your TwitterContext, like this:

```
    var ctx = new TwitterContext(auth);
```

The particular authorizer, in this case, is SingleUserAuthorizer but you can use the same authorizer you used to get the original credentials. Just provide all 4 credentials and LINQ to Twitter will bypass the user re-direct for authorization on Twitter.

Comment: So I can use the `SingleUserAuthorizer` even though my app isn't a single user app? Also, does it have a way to check to see if the access token and secret are still valid (and that the user hasn't revoked access)

Comment: SingleUserAuthorizer was just an example. You can also use the same authorizer you used to make the initial authorization. The key is to load all 4 credentials. You can do an Account/VerifyCredentials (https://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Verifying%20Credentials&referringTitle=Managing%20Accounts) query to see if your application is still authorized.

Comment: @JoeMayo I have a peculiar problem. I have a php code which provides me with OAuth dialog and I log in through that. After that my oauth token and oauth token secret is saved in database. Now I have a c# task which automatically runs in some duration say 1 hr. That code is in .net and I am integrating your linqtotwitter with it. Now my problem is I am not goin to authorize a user through linqtotwitter, as i already authorize user using php code. And in singleuserauthorizer if i hardcode all the values it works fine.

Comment: But there can be different users, now when I get the token value and secret from the database it does not authenticate me.

Comment: Both the tokens and secrets are different, i mean there is one on the dev.twitter.com for my app particularly. but using php the token and secret saved in database does not match with the one on the site

Comment: If it works when you hard-code it, but not when you read from database you will have to debug why the database credentials don't work. Make sure you're saving the right credentials and that they're in the right order. Make sure that you aren't accidentally switching credentials. Make sure you haven't added any spaces to the end of the credential either.